# Are all WPF controls FOCUSable?

Tags: wpf, controls, default, focusable

Are there any default exceptions where wpf controls are not focusable?

My controls need to be all focusable, but I do not want to set everytime I create a control

```
make focusable="true"
```

Answer (score 4):

In general, WPF controls work as expected with regards to being focusable or not.  Things you can interact with such as button, list/items controls, textbox are all focusable.  Non-interactive controls like TextBlock, Image are non-focusable.  So normally, you don't have to deal with setting the value of the Focusable property.  I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but I hope this helps.

Comment: +1 Also, you can use styles to set the Focusable property on all instances of any given control.